# Unable to stream events within a mocked DOM source in CycleJs test

Tags: javascript, cyclejs, xstream-js

Given an isolated component built with CycleJs (the component works fine) :

```js
import isolate from '@cycle/isolate';
import { div, ul, li, a } from '@cycle/dom';

function intent(domSource){
    const changeString$ =  domSource
        .select('.string').events('click')
        .map( ev => ev.target.dataset.position);

    return { changeString$ };
}

function model(actions, props$){

    const { changeString$ } = actions;

    return props$.map( props => {

        return changeString$
            .startWith(props.initialString)
            .map( activePosition => ({ activePosition, preset : props.preset }));

    }).flatten().remember();
}

function view(state$){
    return state$.map( state => (
        div(
            ul(
                state.preset.map( (string, position) => (
                    li(
                        a({
                            attrs : {
                                href : '#',
                                'data-pitch' : string.pitch,
                                'data-frequency' : string.frequency,
                                'data-position' : position,
                                class : ['string', parseInt(state.activePosition, 10) === position ? 'active' : ''].join(' ')
                            }
                        },
                        string.name)
                    )
                ))
            )
        )
    ));
}

function stringSelector(sources){
    const actions = intent(sources.DOM);
    const state$  = model(actions, sources.props);
    const vdom$   = view(state$);

    return {
        DOM: vdom$,
        value: state$
    };
}

export default isolate(stringSelector, '.string-selector');
```

I have *tried* to test the behavior using `@cycle/time` :

```js
import test from 'tape';
import xs   from 'xstream';
import { mockDOMSource } from '@cycle/dom';
import { mockTimeSource } from '@cycle/time';
import stringSelector from '../../../src/js/component/stringSelector/index.js';

test('string selector', t => {

    t.plan(1);

    const Time = mockTimeSource();

    const e2Click$       = Time.diagram('-------x-------|');
    const a2Click$       = Time.diagram('---x------x----|');
    const expectedState$ = Time.diagram('0--1---0--1----|');

    const DOM = mockDOMSource({
        '.string[data-picth=e2]': {
            click: e2Click$
        },
        '.string[data-picth=a2]': {
            click: a2Click$
        },
    });

    const selector = stringSelector({
        DOM,
        props: xs.of({
            preset: {
                strings: [{
                    name: 'E',
                    pitch: 'e2',
                    frequency: 82.41
                }, {
                    name: 'A',
                    pitch: 'a2',
                    frequency: 110.0
                }]
            },
            initialString: 0
        })
    });

    const activePosition$ = selector.value.map( state => state.activePosition );

    Time.assertEqual(activePosition$, expectedState$);

    Time.run(t.end.bind(t));
});
```

But the `activePosition$` stream ends directly. I don't know if it comes from the way the DOM is mocked (the events doesn't seems to be triggered) or the way I build the `activePosition$` stream ?

When running my test, I have the following message :

```
Expected

0--1---0--1----|

Got

(0|)

Failed because:

 * Length of actual and expected differs
 * Expected type next at time 0 but got complete
 * Expected stream to complete at 60 but completed at 0
```

Comment: The original code is available at https://github.com/krampstudio/tuny/tree/dev/cyclejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I spotted the problem.

The thing is, with the mocked DOM driver, you need to create event for the exact same selector as the one used in `DOM.select('...').events`.

In your case you select `.string` but you mock an event on `.string[data-pitch=..]`, which will then not match on the app's side.

Keep in mind that there is no real DOM involved on the testing side.
In your case, when you fake a click on the selector `.string`, no matter what your component renders, it will only generate one event.

I think what you want to achieve here is to fake the data that is in the event.

You can probably do something like this:

```
const clicks = Time.diagram('---0---1----0---|').map(position => {
    // this will create a fake DOM event that contains the properties you are reading
    return {target: {dataset: {position: position }}}
})

const DOM = mockDOMSource({
    '.string': {
        click: clicks
    }
});
```

Comment: Got it, however the stream is still closing after the first value and the event never triggered. I think it's related to the isolation, I've already tried `mockDOMSource({
        '.string-selector': {
            '.string': {
                click: clicks
            }
        }
    });`

Comment: I've also seen `mockDOMSource` has an `isloateSource` method but didn't found how to actually implement it.

Comment: OOohh I see, I missed the fact that you `isolate` FROM the component!!
This is something you don't want to do. Isolation should be on the component's consumer side.
The component itself should not be aware of any isolation

Comment: The consumer might want to isolate with different name, or only isolate a few drivers... 

So to fix your problem, you should just remove the `isolate` from the export

Comment: That was the problem. It looks like I still have a lot to learn in cyclejs